# How to test an app without its sourcecode and not using iPhone or iPad devices?

Tags: iphone, ipad, testing, ios-simulator

I want to do testing on an app which is provided free through iTunes. I do not have the source code of the app, i only have the .ipa file downloaded through iTunes and i do not have an iPhone or an iPad to install it and start my testing on the app . I want to test the app see how it works, write down scenarios and etc without using an iPhone or an iPad. I tried searching for iPhone simulators but i came to know that i cant install any apps on it, installed Xcode but i cannot simulate it until i have the source code which i do not have.

So can anyone suggest me where i can simulate an app which is provided through iTunes without having the source code ?  I just want to see the app, what it provides etc without using an iPhone or iPad device

Many Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app will not run on your Mac. It’s been compiled for the processors in iOS devices, which makes it incompatible with the Intel processor in your Mac. I’d suggest finding a cheap iPhone 3GS or iPod Touch on eBay.

Comment: Many Thanks for your reply. Are there any simulators where i can install the app without buying any devices ? I am a student and i need to test it for only one hour ...

Comment: @kich find someone who would borrow you his iOS device.

Comment: @kich: No. There are no applications that will run iOS applications compiled for iOS devices except for iOS devices.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, i came to know that i can borrow iPad 1 from my university which will be helpful for my use ...